# Moving data from a HashSet to ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, list, data-structures, arraylist, hashset

I have the following `Set` in Java:

```
Set< Set<String> > SetTemp = new HashSet< Set<String> >();
```

and I want to move its data to an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList< ArrayList< String > > List = new ArrayList< ArrayList< String > >);
```

Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You simply need to loop:

```
Set<Set<String>> setTemp = new HashSet<Set<String>> ();
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>> ();
for (Set<String> subset : setTemp) {
    list.add(new ArrayList<String> (subset));
}
```

Note: you should start variable names in small caps to follow Java conventions.

Answer (score 73):

Moving Data `HashSet` to `ArrayList`

```
Set<String> userAllSet = new HashSet<String>(usrAllTemp);
List<String> usrAll = new ArrayList<String>(userAllSet);
```

Here `usrAllTemp` is an `ArrayList`, which has some values. 
Same Way `usrAll(ArrayList)` getting values from `userAllSet(HashSet)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Stream and collector to do this, I hope it is the easiest way

```
listname = setName.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `addAll()`:

```
Set<String> gamesInstalledTemp = new HashSet< Set<String> >();
List<String> gamesInstalled = new ArrayList<>();
gamesInstalled.addAll(gamesInstalledTemp);
```