# How to make ArrayList of hashset in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, data-structures, hashset

I want to make **ArrayList of HashSet** and use it.

#### **My Problem:**

I will get an Integer N as an user input.
I have to make a hashset and put some values in it.
Then add it to ArrayList and above step is to be done N times.
After it I have to check whether a element is present in the first/second/third/... or Nth hashset in ArrayList.

To check value in which hashset is also given by user.

I dont have to convert my ArrayList to hashset either I have to make ArrayList to hashset.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moving data from a HashSet to ArrayList in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13632135/moving-data-from-a-hashset-to-arraylist-in-java)

Comment: Its completely different,I had seen that also but that doesn't helped me.Please read my problem completely and help if you could.

Comment: Create a list of hashsets  (`ArrayList<HasSet>`) and add the sets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make an ArrayList of HashSets :

```
ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>();
```

Then create HashSets, fill them, and put them in your ArrayList normally.

```
HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
set.add(1);
set.add(whateverIntValue);
list.add(set);
```

You can then get the nth HashSet of your list using `list.get(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Set<Integer>> sets = new ArrayList<>();

sets.add(someSet());
sets.add(someSet());
sets.add(someSet());

Set<Integer> someSet() {
    Set<Integer> set = new Hashset<>();
    Collections.addAll(set, 2, 3, 5, 7, 11);
    return set;
}
```

This makes a distinction between **specification** / interface of variables an method parameters and results, and **implementation** / implementing class.

So you can change the implementation, say to a sorted TreeSet without pain.